# How to add a class to more link of a view?

Tags: views, 8

I want to add a class to a views **more link** available under pager section using `template_preprocess_views_view()`.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it by implementing template_preprocess_views_view() in your theme under THEMENAME.theme file as shown below:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_views_view()
 * @param array $vars
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view(&$vars){
  if (YOUR CONDITION FOR ADDING A CLASS){
    $vars['more']['#options']['attributes']['class'] = [
      ENTER YOUR CLASSES AS ARRAY ELEMENTS
    ];
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to add a class to the `.more-link` wrapper instead of the link itself, you can use the following code in the same preprocess function as above:

```php
$variables['more']['#theme_wrappers']['container']['#attributes']['class'] = [
  'more-link',
  'my-class',
];
```

Reference: http://www.drupalthemez.com/blog/d8-adding-class-more-link-view